# How can I output the values I want by using TEXT() version of TODAY() and FIND() in an IF() formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I would like to output "Yes" or "" in column B by using the text version of today's date (e.g. Fri) and finding Fri in  column A with values like Tue, Fri, Sun in them, then making sure that the date today matches the value in that cell within column A before it outputs "Yes".

I'm probably using FIND wrong in this formula I made but I cannot figure out how to use it in a way that it would not give me an error.

Hopefully, someone can help me figure out what I am getting wrong or if I am overcomplicating this.

The formula I used:
=IF((TEXT(TODAY(),"ddd")=FIND((TEXT(TODAY(),"ddd"),A:A))),"Yes","")

What it looks like:
[image: google sheets screenshot]

Example: [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nAWv3fGPNiCekcZg7iYT1ifS1LjjI2XoPKJk3YB0fUM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, TEXT(TODAY(), "ddd")), "Yes", "No")))
```

[image]

Comment: It works, thank you! But could you help me understand how the outer IF makes sense, and how indexed worked with one IF condition?

Comment: @Diwu sure. the INDEX is ARRAYFORMULA (just shorter). and the outer IF translates to: IF A2:A is empty , <output nothing> , else output inner IF

Comment: @Diwu did the answer solve your question?